# How Can I comment my Java code use // instead of ## in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments

When I use Ctrl+/ to comment my code in IDEA, it always ##, not //. It causes a mess when I merge code into others.

```
##import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
##import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

How can I use Ctrl+/ to comment my code using // rather than ##? Like:

```
//import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
//import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```

Comment: This is some weird setup. Is this a `.java` file? IDEA seems to treat this as a language other than java.

Comment: It's a java.vm file, file full name is Cotroller.java.vm

Comment: the file extension `.vm` seems to be associated with [Velocity Template Language](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html), where comments are indicated by `##`. So the question is why your java code is in a file with the `.vm` extension.

Comment: I'm clear now, thanks so much! I'm writing an electrical business backend. The .vm files are built-in framework files.